# How to migrate from Confluent Enterprise Platform paid Kafka, to Confluent Community Edition

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

- does it requires to rebuild the cluster infrastructure?
- can I maintain the current database and data?
- Is there any information how to move to Confluent Community Edition, from Confluent Enterprise Platform, we still want to use rest proxy, (because we use puppet to create topics, acls) and for that we use rest proxy.
- I have build a test cluster to test on this moving

Answer (score 0):

Cluster can stay the same. Just disable any features like Replicator / Cluster Linking, LDAP access, Rebalancer, Enterprise specific Connectors, stop services like Control Center / Metrics Interceptors + Reporters, etc that need the `confluent.license.topic` configuration.

REST Proxy is distributed under Confluent Community License, not Enterprise. Rather than use Puppet, you could use Terraform directly against the Kafka cluster for topics (or you could try to use `kafka-topics.sh` with Puppet calling shell scripts)